# What is a sphere packing?

Tags: coding-theory, packing-problem

We are currently dealing with (n,m,d)-codes (sphere covering bound, sphere packing bound etc.) and one question to solve is:

*We are now looking for a sphere packing of $\{0,1\}^6$ with radius $r$. What is the maximum of $r$, so that the spheres are disjoint?*

I thought, a sphere packing is a maximal set $M$ of spheres such that all spheres are pairwise disjoint. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_packing) only says that it's an arrangement of pairwise disjoint spheres.)

If so, I could just use one sphere with radius $r=6$ and have the entire $\{0,1\}^6$ covered.
Or is the goal to also maximize the size of $M$? Then with $r=2$, I could fit three pairwise disjoint spheres in $M$. That is the maximum for all radii.

Comment: With reference to a $(n,M,d)$ code, the sphere packing bound envisions the space $\{0,1\}^n$  containing $M$ pairwise disjoint spheres of radius $r$. For a given value of $M$, what is the maximum value that $r$ can have such that the spheres are disjoint?

Comment: I'd say it depends on how close the spheres are. But spheres with radius $r$ are disjoint if their distance is at least $2r+1$.